# How to sum json object

Tags: javascript

This is my first time posting here so if there's anything missing or if there isn't much information please let me know. I'm learning on the go.

I pulled up some data from API and now I need to arrange all data so eventually I will stay with only keys and total value of each key.

I need each `storeArea` will sum all the values of `boysTotal` and `girlsTotal` inside each area, so it would look something like this: `[area1`, `3193745.7189541734]`

I started by mapping `json` and came up with 3 different objects for each area, then tried to concat all `boysTotal` and `girlsTotal` into one array so I could sum the total one array with reduce function, but I definitely missing something important. what is it? Thanks for your help!

```
var results = [];

var json = {
    "stores": [
        {
            "storeArea": "area1",
            "totalStore": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "boysTotal": 1082220.3945979946,
                    "girlsTotal": 9585.8794674401543
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "boysTotal": 1056643.6756958894,
                    "girlsTotal": 11018.898987932616
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "boysTotal": 1022322.1218654147,
                    "girlsTotal": 11954.748339502334
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "storeArea": "area2",
            "totalStore": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "boysTotal": 91336.329372028267,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "boysTotal": 78130.417193652393,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "boysTotal": 100755.62136033915,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "storeArea": "area3",
            "totalStore": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "boysTotal": 66604.417069221658,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "boysTotal": 63882.129662868538,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "boysTotal": 108781.84734382466,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "storeArea": "area4",
            "totalStore": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "boysTotal": 0,
                    "girlsTotal": 1452.6775522557543
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "boysTotal": 0,
                    "girlsTotal": 2366.423254655545
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "boysTotal": 0,
                    "girlsTotal": 3485.5840149129986
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "storeArea": "area5",
            "totalStore": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "boysTotal": 3237887.746893588,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "boysTotal": 3218724.4935297123,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "boysTotal": 2925562.2916941536,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "storeArea": "area6",
            "totalStore": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "boysTotal": 291293.35185208195,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "boysTotal": 171962.47103846565,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "boysTotal": 95615.439855929668,
                    "girlsTotal": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
results = json.map(function (x) {
    console.log([x.stores])
    return [x.storeArea, x.totalStore.map(function (y) {
        var subTotal = [[y.boysTotal, y.girlsTotal].reduce(add)]
        return subTotal
    })]
});
```

Comment: `but I definitely missing something important. what is it?` Please post the code you've tried so we can debug it and figure out what's missing

Comment: will do now, dorry

Comment: @CertainPerformance added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using object-orientation?  The json represents stores, and the total array represents days.  Use the store json to build a store.  Its constructor in turn builds an array of days.  We teach a store how to total itself (by reducing it's day total), and we teach a day how to total itself (by adding its boy and girl totals).

```js
class StoreDay {
    constructor(json) {
        this.date = new Date(json.date);
        this.boysTotal = json.boysTotal;
        this.girlsTotal = json.girlsTotal;
    }
    total() {
        return this.boysTotal+this.girlsTotal;
    }
}

class Store {
    constructor(json) {
        this.storeArea = json.storeArea;
        this.days = json.totalStore.map(day => new StoreDay(day));
    }
    
    total() {
        return this.days.reduce((acc, day) => acc + day.total(), 0);
    }
}




var json = {
"stores": [
    {
        "storeArea": "area1",
        "totalStore": [
            {
                "date": "2018-10-01",
                "boysTotal": 1082220.3945979946,
                "girlsTotal": 9585.8794674401543
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-01",
                "boysTotal": 1056643.6756958894,
                "girlsTotal": 11018.898987932616
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-12-01",
                "boysTotal": 1022322.1218654147,
                "girlsTotal": 11954.748339502334
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeArea": "area2",
        "totalStore": [
            {
                "date": "2018-10-01",
                "boysTotal": 91336.329372028267,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-01",
                "boysTotal": 78130.417193652393,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-12-01",
                "boysTotal": 100755.62136033915,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeArea": "area3",
        "totalStore": [
            {
                "date": "2018-10-01",
                "boysTotal": 66604.417069221658,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-01",
                "boysTotal": 63882.129662868538,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-12-01",
                "boysTotal": 108781.84734382466,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeArea": "area4",
        "totalStore": [
            {
                "date": "2018-10-01",
                "boysTotal": 0,
                "girlsTotal": 1452.6775522557543
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-01",
                "boysTotal": 0,
                "girlsTotal": 2366.423254655545
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-12-01",
                "boysTotal": 0,
                "girlsTotal": 3485.5840149129986
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeArea": "area5",
        "totalStore": [
            {
                "date": "2018-10-01",
                "boysTotal": 3237887.746893588,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-01",
                "boysTotal": 3218724.4935297123,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-12-01",
                "boysTotal": 2925562.2916941536,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeArea": "area6",
        "totalStore": [
            {
                "date": "2018-10-01",
                "boysTotal": 291293.35185208195,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-01",
                "boysTotal": 171962.47103846565,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-12-01",
                "boysTotal": 95615.439855929668,
                "girlsTotal": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
};

let stores = json.stores.map(s => new Store(s));
let totals = stores.map(store => {
    return [store.storeArea, store.total()];
});
console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` and `reduce` is the way to go, but you have to `map` into `stores` and `reduce` into `totalStore`:

```js
const json={"stores":[{"storeArea":"area1","totalStore":[{"date":"2018-10-01","boysTotal":1082220.3945979946,"girlsTotal":9585.8794674401543},{"date":"2018-11-01","boysTotal":1056643.6756958894,"girlsTotal":11018.898987932616},{"date":"2018-12-01","boysTotal":1022322.1218654147,"girlsTotal":11954.748339502334}]},{"storeArea":"area2","totalStore":[{"date":"2018-10-01","boysTotal":91336.329372028267,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","boysTotal":78130.417193652393,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","boysTotal":100755.62136033915,"girlsTotal":0}]},{"storeArea":"area3","totalStore":[{"date":"2018-10-01","boysTotal":66604.417069221658,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","boysTotal":63882.129662868538,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","boysTotal":108781.84734382466,"girlsTotal":0}]},{"storeArea":"area4","totalStore":[{"date":"2018-10-01","boysTotal":0,"girlsTotal":1452.6775522557543},{"date":"2018-11-01","boysTotal":0,"girlsTotal":2366.423254655545},{"date":"2018-12-01","boysTotal":0,"girlsTotal":3485.5840149129986}]},{"storeArea":"area5","totalStore":[{"date":"2018-10-01","boysTotal":3237887.746893588,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","boysTotal":3218724.4935297123,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","boysTotal":2925562.2916941536,"girlsTotal":0}]},{"storeArea":"area6","totalStore":[{"date":"2018-10-01","boysTotal":291293.35185208195,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","boysTotal":171962.47103846565,"girlsTotal":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","boysTotal":95615.439855929668,"girlsTotal":0}]}]}

const resp = json.stores.map(store => ([store.storeArea, store.totalStore.reduce((a, e) => a + e.boysTotal + e.girlsTotal, 0)]))

console.log(resp);
```

Comment: I think the destructuring adds more complexity than is necessary for someone new to this who is trying to understand what is going on, store => [store.storeArea, stroe.totalStore.reduce((a, e) => a + e.boysTotal + e.girlsTotal, 0)] is a lot easier for someone new to understand.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I agree, destructuring removed in order to make it simple

Answer (score 0):

```js
var results = [];

var json = {
"stores": [
  {
    "storeArea": "area1",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "boysTotal": 1082220.3945979946,
        "girlsTotal": 9585.8794674401543
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "boysTotal": 1056643.6756958894,
        "girlsTotal": 11018.898987932616
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "boysTotal": 1022322.1218654147,
        "girlsTotal": 11954.748339502334
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area2",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "boysTotal": 91336.329372028267,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "boysTotal": 78130.417193652393,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "boysTotal": 100755.62136033915,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area3",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "boysTotal": 66604.417069221658,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "boysTotal": 63882.129662868538,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "boysTotal": 108781.84734382466,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area4",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "boysTotal": 0,
        "girlsTotal": 1452.6775522557543
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "boysTotal": 0,
        "girlsTotal": 2366.423254655545
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "boysTotal": 0,
        "girlsTotal": 3485.5840149129986
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area5",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "boysTotal": 3237887.746893588,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "boysTotal": 3218724.4935297123,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "boysTotal": 2925562.2916941536,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area6",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "boysTotal": 291293.35185208195,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "boysTotal": 171962.47103846565,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "boysTotal": 95615.439855929668,
        "girlsTotal": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
}

var i = 0;

for (i=0; i<json.stores.length; i++) {
  var store = json.stores[i];

  var j = 0;

  var boysTotal = 0;
  var girlsTotal = 0;

  var result = [];

  for (j=0; j<store.totalStore.length; j++) {
    boysTotal += parseFloat(store.totalStore[j]['boysTotal']);
    girlsTotal += parseFloat(store.totalStore[j]['girlsTotal']);
  }

  results[i] = [];
  results[i][0] = store.storeArea;
  results[i][1] = boysTotal + girlsTotal;
  //results[i][1] = boysTotal;
  //results[i][2] = girlsTotal;

}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was totally wrong with how i dealt with it. I got confused by the console

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will do the work:

```
json.stores.forEach(function(x){
     var totalboys=0, totalgirls = 0; // for clarity & flexibility
     x.totalStore.forEach(function(y){
        totalboys += y.boysTotal;
        totalgirls += y.girlsTotal;
     })
     results[x.storeArea] = totalboys + totalgirls;
     console.log(results[x.storeArea])
})
```

See it in action [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/site2goal/0c1aLqe7/14/)

Answer (score -2):

You can use loadsh to perform operations on your json objects and arrays.

https://lodash.com/docs/

This is a case of reduction for each unique element.

I always use _.groupBy and then _.map the result to an array after applying the reduction. In this case the reduction operation is _.sumBy.

```
var obj = [ {"name":"Jack ProjManager","count":12000}, {"name":"Jack ProjManager","count":750000}, {"name":"Joe ProjManager","count":45000} ]; 

var output = _(obj) .groupBy('name') .map((objs, key) => ({ 'name': key, 'count': _.sumBy(objs, 'count') })) .value(); console.log(output);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: Linking to a library without an example is not an answer